# ムームードメインでexample.comを取得し、CloudFlareをネームサーバーにした状態で、corp.example.comでエックスサーバーのWordPressを表示するためにはどうすればいいか

Tags: network, dns

現在、https://example.com にてあるサービスを運営しており、
その上で、https://corp.example.com で会社HPを表示したい状態です。

- example.comはムームードメインで取得
- https://example.com のサーバーはAWS（ELB）
- CloudFlareをネームサーバーに設定
- 会社HPはWordPressで、エックスサーバーのサーバー上にある

試みたことは、

1. example.comをエックスサーバーに登録
   ⇒すでにムームードメインではCloudFlareをネームサーバーに設定しているため、できず（やり方がわからず）
2. 元々ムームードメインで取得していたexample.bizのネームサーバーをエックスサーバーに設定し、corp.example.biz（comではなくbiz）にて、WordPressをインストールし、CloudFlareからCNAMEでcorp.example.bizを設定
   ⇒できず（無効なURLです。プログラム設定の反映待ちである可能性があります。しばらく時間をおいて再度アクセスをお試しください。となる）
3. 2の状態で半日待ってみる
   ⇒変わらず

どのような設定であれば、https://corp.example.com で会社HPを表示することができるのでしょうか。
もしくはそもそも不可能などあれば教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: CloudFlareで直接エックスサーバー側のネームサーバーをcorp.example.comに対応するNSとして設定、またはエックスサーバーのインスタンスのIPアドレスを直接Aレコードに設定すれば良いように見えます

Comment: 早速のご回答誠にありがとうございます。
下記2つ試してみたのですが、現段階ではダメそうでした。
ただしそれぞれ数時間しか待ってないので、半日ほど待てば反映されるのかも知れません。

>CloudFlareで直接エックスサーバー側のネームサーバーをcorp.example.comに対応するNSとして設定
こちらですが、勉強不足で具体的にどのようにすればいいかわからなかったのですが、下記やってみました。
—試したこと—
CloudFlareのexample.com のドメインのDNS設定にて、
NS corp ns1.xserver.jp
--------------------

> またはエックスサーバーのインスタンスのIPアドレスを直接Aレコードに設定すれば良いように見えます
—試したこと--
CloudFlareのexample.com のドメインのDNS設定にて、
A corp 123.123.123.123（エックスサーバーのサーバー情報に記載されていたIP） 
------------------

もし宜しければ他にもご意見いただけますと大変助かります。

Comment: 少し時間が経って再度確認してみると、エラーの内容が変わりました。`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`となっています。CloudFlareの設定は、`NS corp ns1.xserver.jp`です。

Answer (score 0):

## ムームードメインの設定

ネームサーバをCloudFlareのものに設定してください。設定すべきネームサーバは、CloudFlareのコントロールパネルのDNSのページに記載があります。

## CloudFlareの設定

1. example.comのゾーンを作る
2. `corp`のAレコードを作る。IPアドレスはエックスサーバのものを指定する

上記の通りになっているか、確認または設定してください。

corpに対するNSレコードを作成されているようですが誤りです。削除してください。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。この方法も試しているのですが、丸一日以上経っても、「無効なURLです。プログラム設定の反映待ちである可能性があります。しばらく時間をおいて再度アクセスをお試しください。」となります。

Comment: DNSの設定はおそらく問題なく、エックスサーバーのサーバー側で何かしら設定を間違っている可能性が高いと思いますので、改善してみようと思います。もしも、問題の切り分けに役立つ記事等あれば、教えて頂きたいです。。